# How to do source code listings in ConTeXt?

Tags: listings, context

I am new to LaTeX and ConTeXt, so I hope I am not asking something obvious. I have been able to create a LaTeX document using `\usepackage{listings}`. Now I have discovered ConTeXt. Is it possible to type set (C++) source code listings in ConTeXt as easily as it is in LaTeX using the aforementioned package?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Do I need to get the VIM highlighting files myself or is it part of usual ConTeXt distributions?

Comment: You need to have vim installed and the vim ConTeXt module. Both are not part of the default installation. To install all third party modules, run `first-setup.sh --modules=all`. Vim needs to be installed manually on your system.

Comment: There's also a built-in code listing feature. It's more flexible and faster, but supports far less languages: [ConTeXt wiki - Verbatim](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim) Pick the one more suitable for your task.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).